# Activate Sonar Squid rules so that build fails if the sonar ruleset criteria is not met

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, squid

I am trying to activate my sonar SQUID ruleset so that if the quality standards are not met the build should fail or prevents system from building.

I tried to find its solution on google/maven but there is no maven plugin for squid ruleset.

Any other way to it?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should use the [Build Breaker plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin) to achieve this.

Comment: can this plugin provide functionality to fail build if squid rules requirement is not met.

Comment: As said by @kraal, you should use the Build Breaker plugin, together with a suited quality profile (with squid rules) and quality gate (e.g with an error threshold on number of issues). This might prove a bit strict though, so I would recommend to restrict to blocker and critical issues first (as in the default quality gate).